# Is it possible to parameterize a sass color function?

Tags: css, sass

I'm building a config file for a sass project that will have different themes.

To define button's hovers, I'm using one of the sass color function:

```
darken($bgcolor, 10%);
```

I was wondering if it could be possible to parameterize the function 'darken' so we can define button's hovers behaviour in our config file.

I've tried to set a variable:

```
$button-hover: darken;
```

and then recall it in this way:

```
$button-hover($bgcolor, 10%);
```

but the css output is wrong:

```
background: darken #db8947, 10%;
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to do it?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use this way,

```
$button-hover: darken($bgcolor, 10%);
.item{
   background: $button-hover;
}
```

Comment: I think he wanted a different solution because he might want to replace the `darken` with a `lighten` function for a different theme.

Answer (score -1):

You could make a mock function:

```
@function button-bg($color, $percentage){
    @return darken($color, $percentage);
}
```

now you can use it just like any other function:

```
background: button-bg(#666, 20%);
```

In that case you won't be working with `variables` anymore, so you might want to make your function name more obvious and make it something like `theme-button-bg` or something.